# Reduce Bundle Size with large amount of image - ReactJS + Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I recently update my version of react-script and it updates my webpack as well (webpack@5.88.2). Since then, when I build my ReactJS website, I got a bundle > 50Mo. The reason is I have thousands of icon in PNG in my asset (/src/assets).

Before the update, I managed to reduced the bundle size by using "file-loader" in ly webpack.config.js

But with the update, they change it for asset management even if it's still possible to have the similar behavior. Which is acceptable to reduce the bundle size < 4 Mo

So my question is more generic, why is the best practice to handle thousands pictures in a ReactJS project without having a large bundle ?

Thanks !

Comment: If you have thousands of photos in a project, I think you should be fetching them from a server when needed instead of trying to bundle them into your project